# Can I use expressions in Apache Shiro security annotations?

Tags: spring, security, annotations, shiro

I've been doing some comparisons between Apache Shiro and Spring Security - I'm really loving the security model that Shiro uses and believe it to be far cleaner that Spring Security.

However, one big nice-to-have would be to be able to reference method parameters from within the method-level security annotations. For example, right now I could so something like:

```
@RequiresPermissions("account:send:*")
public void sendEmail( EmailAccount account, String to, String subject, String message) { ... }
```

Within the context of this example, this means that the authenticated user must have the permission to send emails on email accounts.

However, this is not fine-grained enough, as I want instance level permissions! In this context, assume that users can have permissions on instances of email accounts. So, I'd like to write the previous code something like this:

```
@RequiresPermissions("account:send:${account.id}")
public void sendEmail( EmailAccount account, String to, String subject, String message) { ... }
```

In this way, the permission string is referencing a parameter passed into the method such that the method can be secured against a particular instance of EmailAccount.

I know I could easily do this from plain Java code within the method, but it would be great to achieve the same thing using annotations - I know Spring Security supports Spring EL expressions in its annotations.

Is this definitely not a feature of Shiro and thus will I have to write my own custom annotations?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Did you create a new feature request? 
http://shiro.apache.org/issues.html

Comment: Multiple people have added a new feature request for this.  See for example: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-331

Answer (score 8):

Look at the classes in http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authz/aop/package-summary.html, especially `PermissionAnnotationHandler`. There you can see that all Shiro does when encountering the `@RequiresPermissions` annotation is call `getSubject().isPermitted(permission)` and does no substitution inside the annotation value at all. You would have to somehow override that handler if you wanted this kind of functionality.

So to answer your question: yes, this is definitely not a feature of Shiro and you have to either write your own annotation or somehow override that handler.

Comment: @drewzilla I came up to this q/a in the "my tags" view, and I am wondering if the answer isn't correct. Note that negative answers can be answers as well. Could you indicate if anything is missing from the answer?

Answer (score 3):

This feature is currently not supported by Shiro.  Multiple people have requested this feature.  Perhaps we can vote for the issue?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-484

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-77

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-417

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-331

Comment: '${account.id}' this is obviously using Spring's BeanWrapper (reflection). Although it might prevent some lines of code to be written IMHO this is not part of a security framework as Shiro intends to be.

Comment: Great but this is not fixed yet. If we're using Spring, is there any way to use it like other Spring annotation now?